# Parse this Expression !

Tags: c++

Can anyone parse this following expression for me

```
#define Mask(x) (*((int *)&(x)))
```

I applied the popular right-left rule to solve but cant.. :(

Thanks a bunch ahead :)

Comment: Take the address of x, cast this to int*, and then dereference it.

Comment: @nonnb: I'm curious: why do people (like you) put answers in comments instead of in answers?

Comment: The proper C++ way is `reinterpret_cast<int&>(x)`, BTW.

Comment: @Ned, it's a risk-free way to look smart without costing you any possible reputation. Also, your comment is visible right at the top, whether or not it has the most votes--more ego boosting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This defines a macro Mask that interprets its argument as an int.

`&(x)` - address of x...

`(int *)&(x)` - ...interpreted as a pointer to int

`*((int *)&(x))` - the value at that pointer

Answer (score 10):

This just reads out the first `sizeof (int)` bytes at the address of the argument, and returns them as an integer.

Comment: +1 for that, of course, it wouldn't read anything beyond the length of an integer as a result of the cast.

Answer (score 4):

You need to think inside out:

- Find the address of x.
- cast this to an integer pointer
- dereference this pointer to return the value.

As such, `int y = Mask(something);` returns an integer interpretation of `something`.

Answer (score 4):

To keep it simple:

```
#define Mask(x) reinterpret_cast<int&>(x)
```

I am assuming that there is no `const_cast`, that is, that the argument `x` is of non-const type, else there would be an extra `const_cast` in there.

Comment: Very cute - some basic things really were improved in C++

Comment: Thanks a lot for suggesting me an modern alternate :)

Answer (score 2):

This kind of macro can cast a `float` value to a `DWORD` in it's binary form and vice versa. This can be used with libraries that have functions using `DWORD` as generic input types.

An example would be `SetRenderState()` in DirectX :

```
HRESULT SetRenderState(
  D3DRENDERSTATETYPE state,
  DWORD value
);
```

In this particular case, some `state` require you to give a `float` value. Now, trying to pass `6.78f` directly to that function would truncate `6.78f` to an integer which would be `6`. What we want is the binary form `0x40D8F5C3` so that the library will be able to cast it back to `6.78f`.

That's what we call a reinterpret cast. It's platform dependent and potentialy dangerous unless you know what you are doing.

Comment: ):) Thanks fo the the great additional info